# Заполнение пустого массива значениями HashMap

Tags: java, массивы, map

Всем доброго времени суток!
В качестве обучения пишу программку для подсчета голосов.

Вот код:

```
public class Kata_7_3 {
    public static String getWinner(final List<String> listOfBallots) {
        //Your code
        int votesGiven = listOfBallots.size();// Кол-во проголосовавших

        String winnerName = "";

        ArrayList<String> uniqueNamesOfCandidates = candidates(listOfBallots); // Получение списка уникальных имен

        HashMap<String,Integer> resultOfVote = new HashMap<>();// Мапа с кандидатами и голосами

        for(String name : uniqueNamesOfCandidates){
            int votes = 0;
            for (int j = 0;j< listOfBallots.size();j++){
                if(Objects.equals(name, listOfBallots.get(j))){
                    votes++;
                }
                resultOfVote.put(name,votes);
            }
        }
        int [] valVotes = new int[resultOfVote.size()];
        
        for (HashMap.Entry<String,Integer> entry : resultOfVote.entrySet()){
            Arrays.fill(valVotes, entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valVotes));
        return winnerName;
    }

    /**
     * Метод получает на вход параметр List ballots, и возвращает список уникальных кандидатов
     * @param ballots Бюллетени. Список, где указаны кандидаты. Сколько раз указан кандидат в списке,
     *                столько за него отдано голосов
     * @return возвращает ArrayList кандидатов
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> candidates (List<String>ballots){
        Set<String> candidates = new HashSet<>(ballots);
        ArrayList<String> listOfNamesOfCandidates = new ArrayList<>(candidates);
        return listOfNamesOfCandidates;
    }
}
```

Логика этого кода такая:

1. На входе получаем список такого формата: *"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B","Safa","C","C","C","C","C","C"*
2. Потом в методе **candidates** получаем список просто кандидатов
3. За тем, создаем мапу с именем и количеством голосов

А вот дальше мне надо посчитать кто же победил.
Я думал вывести значения в массив и там уже сделать подсчеты в массиве, а потом по поиску ключ-значения вывести победителя.

Это я пытаюсь сделать тут:

```
int [] valVotes = new int[resultOfVote.size()];

for (HashMap.Entry<String,Integer> entry : resultOfVote.entrySet()){
    Arrays.fill(valVotes, entry.getValue());
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valVotes));
return winnerName;
```

Но, в массив добавляется кол-во голосов только одного, последнего кандидата в мапе
Вот так получается:  `[1, 1, 1, 1]`

Подскажите, как мне заполнить массив значениями из мапы таким образом, чтобы значения соответствовали каждому кандидату. По типу: `[4, 7, 1, 5]`

Comment: Ну вместо этого `Arrays.fill(valVotes, entry.getValue());` попробуйте в нужный индекс массива писать число

Comment: Метод Arrays.fill() заполняет все элементы массива числом которое ты передал, чтобы записать в массив нужно обращаться по его индексу и записывать значения

Comment: Через цикл for? Пробовал. Тоже самое получается. Можно привести пример такого цикла? Может я просто с циклом туплю(

Comment: @Alex_Lynx заведи переменную counter снаружи цикла и итерируй её внутри цикла, а дальше записывай в массив так valVotes[counter] = entry.getValue(), если хочешь то могу написать более лаконичное решение твой задачи со стримами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется со стримами немного красивее выходит. Правда тут есть недостаток, если будет 2 и более кандидаты с одинаковым количеством голосов, то выдаст первого. Но ты можешь и сам подумать как это исправить, либо может быть ты так и задумывал)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        String name = getName(List.of("A", "A","A","A", "A", "B", "B", "B","Safa","C","C","C","C","C","C"));
    }
}

private static String getName(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Нет кандидатов"))
            .getKey();
}
```

Либо если не хочешь использовать стримы, то аналогичное решение без них

```
private static String getName(List<String> list) {
    if(list.isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Нет кандидатов");

    Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String s : list) {
        map.merge(s, 1L, Long::sum);
    }

    return Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)